# Replace windows controls with custom ones

Tags: windows, winapi, com

I've been trying to search for ways to change the way windows controls look.
For instance change the OpenFileDialog UI at a windows level, or completely turn the file copy/delete/move dialog into something else, like a series of disks or a bucket filling up with liquid.

Looking around i found that i could write a com app that could be used instead of the default windows ones. But i have no idea where or how to start with these, or even how i could see what i would have to implement to achieve this, nor how i would be able to tell windows to use my custom ones instead of the default ones.

Have tried looking in the microsoft documentation, and i'm 99% sure i'm either unable to search for what i need or it's undocumented.

I know there are some apps from Stardock that could do this where i could just make the graphics, but where's the fun in that?

Anybody able to point me in the right direction?

Interested only in being able to achieve this for windows 10.

Comment: There is no documented way to do this. You'll have to hack it up yourself.

Comment: Well that's a shame, was hoping somebody might know something so i don't go in blind.

Comment: As a side note. Why is the question getting downvoted? It's a pretty reasonable and specific request for information i've not been able to uncover by myself. Except some articles that were written for Vista

Comment: As I said, there is nothing documented or supported so you need to reverse engineer it. And it's a very broad and vague question because of that. Which I guess explains the voting. Really the question should be closed and removed.

Answer (score 0):

You could in theory write your own implementations of `IFileOpenDialog` and `IFileSaveDialog` and overwrite the Windows registrations in `HKCR\CLSID`. This might not affect older applications that use the older open/save common dialogs.

There is also `CLSID_ProgressDialog` and some progress related interfaces you could take over but I don't know if Explorer actually uses these or its own custom version.

This could obviously break your system so you really have to know what you are doing if you go down this path.

While you are developing this you could choose to selectivity inject into a limited set of processes and hook `CoCreateInstance` instead.

Changes to [existing dialogs](http://www.askvg.com/transform-windows-xp-into-windows-7-without-using-customization-pack/) (adding/moving/hiding controls and images) can be done with [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/). This was pretty easy in the 90's but it is more problematic these days because some files are protected and Windows updates are more common.